# AGS Tiled Map Services and the .jpg file extension using js api

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tiles

I have an old app that is still using esri js api 1.4 (i know, it's dated) but that app works and it can pull tiles from a 10.0 tiled map services. When it does that it calls for the tiles at the url with the \000\111\222 type format. It also appends a '.jpg' to the end of the request url. That works fine - i can even knock off the '.jpg' and still get the tile image. 
But now, my tiled service is being updated to 10.2 and I'm having some issues. When the request goes out with the .jpg I am no longer able to get the image - i get a 400 invalid url.
If i lop off the .jpg then i get the image. 
The problem is that i'm not the one adding the .jpg to the request. That is the old api interacting with the ags service to produce that call. It's a black box to me. I load the layer and the js api does it's thing.

Am i missing something or is my js api just too old to keep working?

Comment: definitely time to upgrade.

Comment: would be easier to justify the upgrade if i could find solid written evidence, from esri preferably, that says this is the reason why it is not working

Comment: How are you accessing the tiled layer? can you share the code for that? You could also try to make a custom layer, and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on maintaining/upgrading a web application, its typically a good idea to leave the services that it utilizes alone as well.  Because version 1.4 of the Esri JavaScript API was released years and years before ArcGIS Server was re-engineered/redesigned in its current native 64 bit form, there was no way for the developers to ensure that it would be forward compatible.

I would love to be able to point you at some 'official' documentation to reinforce this point, but to be honest we don't test/certify such disparate combinations of our products.

The closest thing I can find is a discussion that i participated in the Esri forums in which I explained the same limitation with our plugins for Google and Bing maps which are no longer being developed.

https://geonet.esri.com/message/352928?sr=search&searchId=3e5a990e-69b6-4092-8dcb-20df2c83d055&searchIndex=0#352928

let me know if you have any questions/concerns.  i'd be happy to chat further.